# Adding elements to editable form using h:dataTable without submitting all the rows

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, jsf-2

Just wondering if it is possibly to dynamically add elements (in AJAX fashion) to a form using `h:dataTable` without always submitting the current contents? Normally one has to always send the full contents of the datatable, because the whole datatable is re-rendered. If the datatable gets big (say, 100 rows) this can radically slow down the page, as each row always gets posted.

Doing this with raw JS this is not a problem, but can it be avoided with JSF? Of course if we don't send all the row data with the AJAX request, it remains lightweight, but we will lose all the changes made to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JSF, which re-renders the whole component when making changes on it, this is simply not possible.

As the whole component is re-rendered, all changes to it are lost except when they are submitted to the server before refresh.

JSF is designed in a way that this is not (easily) possible. One good hack to this would be to keep track of those rows that have been modified and then submit only those. This can be achieved by attaching a change listener to each field in the form.

Answer (score 1):

[PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org) has a datatable with ability to add rows without always submitting the current content.

You can see [datatable ajax](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprDataTable.jsf) example.

Follow the instructions of [getting started](http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html).

Comment: True, that's one way to do it (to keep the edit form separate from the actual listing). I don't, however, see what extra benefits PrimeFaces brings in this case? The same could be achieved with stock JSF 2.0. Also, what I am actually looking for is to have the datatable itself work as a form, so each row would have one or more input fields (this makes a more convenient UI for editing long lists quickly).

Comment: if you look in PrimeFaces datatable, you can see that they have an editable table as well.

Comment: Yeah, but that's still not the same. That one submits one row at a time - you have to click specific save button for each row. I want all the lines editable by default. Sorry, I should've been more specific in my question. Anyway, maybe the right workaround here would be to auto-submit when user jumps from one row to another (if that row was modified). Then there would be no need to submit all the rows when adding new, as changes from all the rows would be already saved to the server. This would still make some excess traffic (lots of AJAX requests at least), but could be a viable solution.